# Adding an attribute to datatables column filtering

Tags: jquery, attributes, datatables

I am using **datatables JQuery plugin** to display the data from my database. I want to do something custom which is not supported by datatables and I came up with a solution that requires me to use AngularJS.

The problem is that I do not know how to **add** a **new attribute** in the search filter of datatables. A solution I found after a search on google was to add the following line but I does not seem to work:

`$('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "enter seach terms here");`

Does anyone here have any other solution?

Comment: can you post your generated HTML code, maybe from firebug ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is working. So , the only thing i suspect being wrong is the invocation of the code.

You need to call it either after the `datatable` is loaded in `document.ready` like ,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",});
   $('.dataTables_filter input').prop("placeholder", "enter search terms here");
});
```

Or, you can use the [fnDrawCallback](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks) function which is invoked every-time `datatable` is loaded.

```
 $('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers","fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
       $('.dataTables_filter input').prop("placeholder", "enter seach terms here");
    }});
```

### And, here is the [Working JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upenrao/HEDvf/7/light/).

Comment: The $(document).ready(function() { //code I posted }); code did its magic. Thank you a lot! I did not even think about using this approach.